# xy scatter plotting wrong values

Tags: excel, vba, scatter-plot

I have a script generating a large amount of xy scatter diagrams from data I have stored in a sheet. It looks like this:

```
1 3.16  4
2 3.2   4
3 3.14  4
4 3.01  4
5 2.98
6 3.04
7 3.23 
8 3.5   3
9 3     3
10 2.93 3
11 2.91 3
12 3.03
13 3.13
```

First number is the row number, second number is the desired `x` value, third number is the desired `y` value. As you can see, there are a few blank spaces here. Somehow these blank spaces corrupt the chart. The row number now becomes the `x` value and the desired `y` value becomes the name of the point.

When I select, for instance, datapoint 2 it shows me this: `series "design" point "4" (2, 3.2)`

I checked if the cells are really empty by using `=countblanks("range")` which results in a positive number. So they are blank and not just formatted incorrectly I guess.

The charts that don't have empty cells in their data ranges function correctly.

How can I make Excel use the correct `x` and `y` values?

Comment: Maybe fill the empty cells with zeros?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what is happening when data is missing and what you wnat to happen? If you want the points connected with a line/curve on the graph then Excel provides 3 possibilities: (A) Leave a gap in the curve --- the line will have a break when data is missing; (B) Set the missing values to zero; and (C) Connect with a line --- this line/curve connects the data points on either side of the missing data.  If you don't connect the data points with a line, Excel just plots points where both X and Y are provided. These options are available via the `Select Data` button in XL2010.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you Right-Click on the chart > Select Data > Add:
Series X Values: `=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$13`
Series Y values: `=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$13`

or equivalently `=Sheet1!$B:$B` and `=Sheet1!$C:$C` or the range you need

Comment: Manually changing the series doesn't help. Only when I manually change it to not include any empty cells the plot is shown correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If even just one of the cells of the first data series (intended for the x axis) contains text that is not empty and does not look like a number, then Excel (at least Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2204)) produces a non-scatterplot if you ask for a scatterplot.  It looks like the non-scatterplot ignores the entire first data series and instead shows the row number along the x axis.

Note that whitespace is "text that is not empty and does not look like a number", so if the value in some cells of the first data series consist of one or more whitespace characters then you get the non-scatterplot.  This case is hard to spot, because a cell with only some whitespace in it looks just like an empty cell.

So try replacing whitespace values with empty values in the data series intended for the x axis.

It is not a problem if the data series intended for the y axis contains non-blank non-numeric values.  Those appear to be ignored, and you get a proper scatter plot displaying the points for which both coordinates are numeric.

It is a shame that the data series intended for the x axis isn't treated the same way.  I would much prefer that at least the data points for which both coordinates are OK would get displayed properly.